# Cannot delete surefirebooster

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse workspace (Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200) on a Windows 10 system. After i check-out a project and try to build it using Maven clean, it gives a build failure. This is the error I get

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XYZ:: SU 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://XYZ/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://XYZ/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://XYZ/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://XYZ/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ geodis-su ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Documents\workspace\XYZ\XYZ-su\target
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.300 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-17T14:35:56+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/284M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project geodis-su: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\Documents\workspace\XYZ\XYZ-su\target\surefire\surefirebooter82744427512387012.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If I restart my PC, I can delete this file (and the entire project), but when I checkout this project again in my workspace I get the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check Java processes on your computer using `jps -m`
2. Then kill for example `taskkill /F /PID 30503`

Answer (score 5):

Steps below to forcefully kill it via command prompt

1. jps -m
2. taskkill /PID  /F

Answer (score 0):

You may have a java program running with a surfire jar. To see it, launch a jps command (this is a soft provide with the JDK) you will have the process, and then you can kill it.

Answer (score 0):

There must a java process that's running in the background which runs the surefire jar. Try killing all the java tasks from task manager and then try deleting the surefire jar or try doing maven clean now.